# Dual-boots directly into Ubuntu without GRUB screen showing and the screen keeps flickering

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, grub-efi

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 to dual boot with Windows10 on Asus A555L laptop day before yesterday and it worked fine for 2 days.

However now when I boot my laptop, it directly goes to Ubuntu without showing the GRUB screen.

Also the screen keeps flickering.

On running boot-repair it generated this link(if this might help you solve the query):

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yJWq6yRGzH

Could you please suggest some measures. Thank you.

I might have switched off my laptop directly from the power button the last time I was working with Windows. Did this create the problem? Is the screen flickering and absence of grub screen related in any way (because both of these problems made an appearance at the same time)?

Comment: when you are in Ubuntu, try installing grub-customizer and it may solve the problem. http://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/03/11/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-18-04-lts/

Comment: flickering screen would be video issue. But grub only boots working Windows. And forced shutdown of Windows often requires chkdsk. Or Windows is still hibernated which are the issues the Boot-Repair report shows. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions  You really need to use your Windows repair flash drive to make Windows repairs. You may be able to directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu & f8 into its internal repair console.

Comment: I can't get into the UEFI boot menu. The methods listed on the Asus website (pressing ESC or f2 while switching on your laptop) just take me to a black screen. I have a Windows repair flash drive but it's useless as long as I can't get into the UEFI boot menu.